# Spring + Hibernate exception mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I encountered an error when the application starts. I do not really understand why this error occurs and how it can be corrected. I got this excеption (i do not show all traceback):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssStreamServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.rssviewer.dao.RssStreamDAO com.rssviewer.service.RssStreamServiceImpl.rssStreamDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssStreamDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.rssviewer.dao.RssStreamDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.rssviewer.domain.RssStream"/>
```

My hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
      ">

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->
    <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:/home/ivan/projects/Java/RssViewer/test.db" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
          <!--p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />-->

</beans>
```

File hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">com.applerao.hibernatesqlite.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
                Existing data will be deleted! -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="com.rssviewer.domain.RssStream"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My dependencies:

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.applerao</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernatesqlite</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

How do I fix this error? If you need something else to put, please write.

Comment: Try upgrading to Hibernate 4.0

Comment: Nice, i change to hibernate 4 and fix problem. Now i have next exception....

Comment: What is the exception now?

Comment: Problem with sqlite dialect. Did you know sqlite dialect for hibernate 4? I get `java.lang.nosuchfielderror` for field `STRING`

Comment: You have 2 different versions of hibernate in your app. Check your pom also check for transitive dependencies.

Comment: @underdog, i check this. Now i have hibernate 4. Its ok. But i how problem with sqlite dialect.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:** 
open `hibernate.cfg.xml` file and set the

> hibernate.dialect

configuration property to be

> org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect

instead of

> com.applerao.hibernatesqlite.dialect.SQLiteDialect

**Updated:**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
 </session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hope this will work.

Comment: Were i can found `com.applerao.hibernatesqlite.dialect.SQLiteDialect`?

Comment: u can see `hibernate.dialect` property in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. under the  `<session-factory>` tag.

Comment: `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` will work with Sqlite?

Comment: Because you are using Maven u should little bit change in your `pom.xml`
open `pom.xml` and replace the dependency of `hibernatesqllite` with

    <!-- hibernate sqlite dialect -->
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.applerao</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernatesqlite</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>